# Forest local versus global style

Tags: tikz-styles, forest

This is something that has been frustrating me for an hour or two. Usually I maintain forest styles locally within each image. I have one particular forest that has been driving me insane, but I am sure I am doing something completely stupid.

The below MWE will compile as it is, but will not compile when the tikzset is commented and the two identical commented lines are uncommented. Why not?
The error is "I do not know the key '/tikz/belowab"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
aboveab/.style={midway,  above,  font=\scriptsize,  text width=1.5cm,  align=center},
belowab/.style={midway,  below,  font=\scriptsize,  text width=1.5cm,  align=center}}

\begin{forest} 
%aboveab/.style={midway,  above,  font=\scriptsize,  text width=1.5cm,  align=center},
%belowab/.style={midway,  below,  font=\scriptsize,  text width=1.5cm,  align=center},
for tree={
  grow=east,
  draw=blue,
  circle,
  line width=0.2pt,
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  edge={draw=blue},
  edge label={\Huge\color{black}},
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- ([xshift=-1.6cm].child anchor) --    
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=2cm,
} 
[,rectangle, s sep=35pt,
  [,edge label={node[belowab]{Text}}
    [,edge label={node[belowab]{Text}}
    ]
    [,edge label={node[aboveab]{Text}}
    ]
  ]
  [,edge label={node[aboveab]{Text}}
    [,edge label={node[belowab]{Text}}
    ]
    [,edge label={node[aboveab]{text}}
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

A forest prefix of the form below will however work

```
\begin{forest}
parentab/.style={align=center,text width=2cm,fill=green!20,rounded corners=2pt},
childab/.style={align=center,text width=3.5cm,fill=green!50,rounded corners=6pt},
grandchildab/.style={fill=pink!50,text width=3.3cm},
for tree={%
    thick,
    drop shadow,
    l sep=0.6cm,
    s sep=0.8cm,
    node options={draw,font=\sffamily},
    edge={semithick,-Latex},
    where level=0{parentab}{},
    where level=1{
        minimum height=1cm,
        childab,
        parent anchor=south west,
        tier=p,
        l sep=0.25cm,
        for descendants={%
            grandchildab,
            minimum height=0.6cm,
            anchor=150,
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
                (!to tier=p.parent anchor) |-(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
        }
    }{},
}
[Drawing\\diagrams
    [Defining node and arrow styles
```

Likewise this works

```
\begin{forest}
m/.style={fill=color1!30},
f/.style={fill=color1!60,text=white},
h/.style={fill=color2!30},
  for tree={
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=east,
    grow'=east,%
  %minimum size=1cm,%new possibility  (note how did \\
  text width=4cm,%
    draw,
    anchor=west,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (.child anchor) -| +(-5pt,0) -- +(-5pt,0) |-
        (!u.parent anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  }
[Delivery Strategy\\for H/4154/2014
    [Procurement Strategy
        [Proposal overview
            [Stakeholders]
            [Vulnerabilities,f]
            [Overview programme,f]          
            [Staff skill requirements]          
        ]
        [Programme]
        [Market-engagement\\strategy]
        [Tender strategy]       
        [Engagement of personnel]               
        [Compliance \& \\Governance strategy,m] 
    ]
    [Rationale for\\procurement
        [Assumed background,h]
        [Rationale for recommendations,m
            [Legal requirements,m]          
            [Client requirements,m]         
            ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message obtained commenting out the `\tikzset`  and using the local settings tells you the problem:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/belowab' and I am going 
to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

The key processor expects keys of the form `/tikz/...` so you need to set the local path to `/tikz` for the keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
/tikz/aboveab/.style={midway,  above,  font=\scriptsize,  text width=1.5cm,  align=center},
/tikz/belowab/.style={midway,  below,  font=\scriptsize,  text width=1.5cm,  align=center},
for tree={
  grow=east,
  draw=blue,
  circle,
  line width=0.2pt,
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  edge={draw=blue},
  edge label={\Huge\color{black}},
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- ([xshift=-1.6cm].child anchor) --    
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=2cm,
} 
[,rectangle, s sep=35pt,
  [,edge label={node[belowab]{Text}}
    [,edge label={node[belowab]{Text}}
    ]
    [,edge label={node[aboveab]{Text}}
    ]
  ]
  [,edge label={node[aboveab]{Text}}
    [,edge label={node[belowab]{Text}}
    ]
    [,edge label={node[aboveab]{text}}
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The following explanation was kindly provided by **Sašo Živanović** (the package author) in a [`comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256359/forest-local-versus-global-style/256361?noredirect=1#comment613970_256361):

> When `forest` encounters an unknown key (that's in a `/forest` path) in
>   the specification of a node (i.e. after the content), it automatically
>   appends the key to keylist node options, which is passed to tikz when
>   creating the node (the path is then automatically changed to `/tikz`). When
>   creating an edge label, you're creating the node directly in tikz:
>   note that tikz syntax is employed, `edge
>   label={node[aboveab]{Text}}` with node options in square brackets. Such
>   styles must therefore be created in `/tikz` path.

Comment: Well that makes sense - but I am still confused where and why the /tikz/ prefix is required, because I don't usually use it (for example the forest preamble added to the second part of the question does work -- no prefix

Comment: When `forest` encounters an unknown key (that's in a `/forest` path) in the specification of a node (i.e. after the content), it automatically appends the key to keylist `node options`, which is passed to `tikz` when creating the node (path is then automatically changed to `/tikz`).  When creating an edge label, you're creating the node directly in `tikz`: note that `tikz` syntax is employed, `edge label={node[aboveab]{Text}}`with node options in square brackets. Such styles must therefore be created in `/tikz` path.

Comment: @Sašo Živanović I'll add this information to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn I updated my answer with an explanation provided by the package author clarifying when it's needed to explicitly set the path to `\tikz`.